# Get month and day from a Date Picker custom field

Tags: custom-post-types, php, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields, date

I've got a custom field called fecha_del_evento from which I want to obtain the day and the month in different formats; day in numbers, and month with the 3 first letters.

The code I'm using is a custom loop inside other cpt, the full code is:

```
<!-- EVENTOS -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12"><h2 class="seccion">Tour</h2></div>
        <?php
        $today = current_time('Ymd');

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'evento',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => '-1',
            'meta_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'key' => 'artista_del_evento', 
                    'value' => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"',
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                    ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'fecha_del_evento',
                    'compare' => '>=',
                    'value' => $today,
                    )
                ),
            'meta_key' => 'fecha_del_evento',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            );

        $query = new WP_Query($args);
        if ($query->have_posts()) :
            while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); 
        ?>

        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <?php
                $datetime_string = get_field('fecha_del_evento');
                $datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '$datetime_string');
                $month = date('M', strtotime($datetime));
                $day = date('d', strtotime($datetime));
            ?>
            <?php echo $day; ?>
            <?php echo $month; ?>
        </div>


    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

    </div><!-- #row -->
</div><!-- #container -->
```

The specific part is the following one, in which I used two different types;
- one with ***date_i18n*** instead of date, which returns the current day,
- -the current one with ***date***, which returns 01 Jan:

```
    <?php
        $datetime_string = get_field('fecha_del_evento');
        $datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '$datetime_string');
        $month = date('M', strtotime($datetime));
        $day = date('d', strtotime($datetime));
    ?>
    <?php echo $day; ?>
    <?php echo $month; ?>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? What does `var_dump($datetime)` give? Maybe you need to leave away the strtotime?

Comment: @giraff I'm trying to obtain the custom field day and month values, to display and style them as I want into the template. The code I wrote above is the one I'm using and the result obtained is not the stored data.